# Why does a UITextField as a subview of a custom UITableViewCell inhibit the scrolling of the parent UITableView?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, ios7

I have created `EDITableViewCell`, a subclass of `UITableViewCell`, so that I can put a `UITextField` inside of it, rather than a `UILabel`. I use `EDITableView` when overriding `tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:`. I populate a few cells with dummy data when initializing the app. The app seems to run fine. The `UITableView` is displayed as expected with three rows of the table populated with dummy data. The problem I am experiencing has do with scrolling the table.

- If I pull up or down on the middle of any of the populated rows, there is **no** scrolling in response.
- If I pull up or down on the middle of any of the unpopulated rows (something below the third row), there *is* scrolling in response, as would be expected with any `UITableView`. Because there are only three items, the table view bounces right back to where it was on touch up.
- If I pull up or down on the edges of any of the populated rows (the portions of the cell that the `UITextField` doesn't extend to), there *is* scrolling in response as well.

Note: I have experienced this same (mis)behavior both with a programmatically-created subclassed `UITableViewCell` approach as well as with a prototype Storyboard approach.

It seems to me that the `UITextField` is in some way inhibiting the scrolling of my `UITableView`. Why would this be happening?

If this is inevitable, how would I go about creating a `UITableViewCell` subclass that does allow for in-place editing without inhibiting the scrolling?

Motivation: Like the *edit event* portion of Apple's Calendar app and many ToDo list apps, I want a UITableView full of cells that can be edited in-place, as opposed to segueing or using modals to edit elsewhere.

Answer (score 1):

The issue here is having a UIResponder object (your UITextField) that is capturing the tap event and basically *holding* it so the UIScrollView (your table view) does not receive those events. A couple of suggestions for you to try:

- Create a UITextField subclass that forwards touch events to the next responder.
- Disable user interaction on the text field, and program when you want it to respond by calling `becomeFirstResponder` when needed.

For the first suggestion, your subclass would do something like this:

```
- (void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{
    [self.nextResponder touchesBegan:touches withEvent:event];
}
```

But of course you would need to forward the other UIResponder methods as well.